# What is PKG_PATH for linux?

Tags: suse, pkgsrc

I am using pkgsrc to install rootless packages in a linux environment.

I don't know much about pkgsrc, but it seems need an environment variable PKG_PATH to download packages.

My linux distribution version is
`SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11`

I want to know how what is PKG_PATH for my linux?

Comment: You might consider adding contextual information about which Linux environment, how you're using pkgsrc, what you've tried, and why you want to know about PKG_PATH.

Comment: If you just want to know its value, do `printenv PKG_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anyone providing binary pkgsrc packages for Linux that may be installed in one's `$HOME`. I don't even know if this is possible (very likely not). "Linux" is a many-coloured thing, and shared libraries etc. will be different on different Linux systems.

Your best bet would probably be to bootstrap pkgsrc with a local installation prefix, for example `$HOME/sw` or `$HOME/local` (unless you're already using this for other things), and build and install packages from source. This work well and I've done that on a number of systems.

Joyent provides pre-built pkgsrc packages for Linux (RHEL, Oracle Linux, CentOS and Scientific Linux), but requires these to be installed with `sudo`: http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/install-on-linux/